# php strtotime is choking on time zone string

Tags: php, date, strtotime

```
<?php 

echo "Hello?";
$thetime = strtotime("Wed Dec 16 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"); 
var_dump($thetime);

?>
```

This code evaluates to "bool(false)"; however, just removing "(Eastern Standard Time)" allows the strtotime function to evaluate correctly. Any ideas why strtotime is choking on the time zone bit of the string?

Comment: Is there a reason for that anyway? GMT is enought ..

Comment: It isn't necessary, just how javascript's date() function returns the date, which is what I was passing to the php processing function. I obviously could change the date format being passed; however, I was curious if strtotime simply can not handle parenthesis or if there is some other issue I am unaware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears so david, in this case you should either formulate a regular expression or manually split up your string.. but I think you want to use the following code:

```
<?php
$new_date_str = preg_replace('\s\(.*\)','',$_POST['your_js_date']);
$new_date = strtotime($new_date_str);
?>
```

This may help :)